# How does InetAddress find the IP of a given hostname?

Tags: java, dns, inetaddress

How does InetAddress work? How does it find an IP address of a hostname.

I understand we can use InetAddress in Java for DNS resolutions, but I would like to know how it works. How does it find a DNS server to resolve the address?

I recently saw a misconfigured `cname`, which was **not** being resolved correctly by InetAddress. It was getting resolved intermittently, but failing most of the times. The `dig` command succeeded on the same machine all the time. Although after fixing the configuration, `InetAddress` worked consistently too. But I don't understand why it was succeeding intermittently before. Either it should have failed consistently or succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

According to Javadoc, Java's `InetAddress` class uses the machines network configuration as strategy to resolve a hostname.

From http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/net/InetAddress.java or https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/InetAddress.html (The InetAddress source):

> Host Name Resolution
> Host name-to-IP address resolution is accomplished through the use of a combination of local machine configuration information and network naming services such as the Domain Name System (DNS) and Network Information Service(NIS). The particular naming services(s) being used is by default the local machine configured one. For any host name, its corresponding IP address is returned.

This means, that if there are multiple networks, or multiple DNS-servers configured for a single network, you may get varying results in resolution, because different hosts might apply different leniency towards fixing broken addresses.

As to why another application might succees more often depends on their resolution strategy.

Comment: If it uses the machine information itself, shouldn't it have same output as `dig`?

Comment: IMO it could very well be that `dig` and your Java program were influencing each other via the local DNS cache. Let us assume `dig` somehow handles the broken CNAME in a smarter way or sends different variants of DNS requests to the server if the canonical CNAME cannot be resolved. That could lead to the reply being in the DNS cache for a while, which might explain why the Java program succeeds in those cases. After the cache entry would have expired, the Java program might be unable to resolve it again until you run `dig` again. But this is pure speculation.

Comment: @OptimusPrime, after some feedback to my comment I could decide whether I should turn it into an answer or not. You can test the hypothesis by manually emptying the DNS cache in between calls with both tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using `InetAddress.getByName(String)` there are a couple of factors that can contribute to inconsistent results:

1. It returns only the first address from a call to `InetAddress.getAllByName(String)`,
2. Repeated queries for the same address are cached, even negative results,
3. If a query is not in the cache, it is forwarded to the platform name resolution service. For both [Windows](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11/blob/37115c8ea4aff13a8148ee2b8832b20888a5d880/src/java.base/windows/native/libnet/Inet4AddressImpl.c#L64) and [Unixes](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11/blob/37115c8ea4aff13a8148ee2b8832b20888a5d880/src/java.base/unix/native/libnet/Inet4AddressImpl.c#L105) this results in a call to `getaddrinfo`.

What this function does is platform specific. On Linux with glibc, this is configured through [gai.conf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/gai.conf.5.html) and [nsswitch.conf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html). This consults many databases (almost always the `/etc/hosts` file), before falling back to the `dns` database. You can obtain a similar result with:

```
getent hosts <host_name>
```

Summarizing, what you obtained with `dig` is just the last one of a long sequence of steps.